# how to open a link in new window with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello Developers Globally, pls i require help with laravel controller, i have a function which generates a link for whatsapp msg and i would love to open this link in new tab without closing the current page,pls below is my function code

```
  public function whatsapp(Request $request)
{ 
    $whatsapp_log = new WhatsappLog();
    $whatsapp_log->telephone = request('tele') ?? request('inp');
    $whatsapp_log->calling_no = request('inp');
    $whatsapp_log->text = request('check') ? request('check') . '>' . request('txt') : request('txt');
    $whatsapp_log->log_by = auth()->user()->name;
    $whatsapp_log->save(); 
    $mail = mail::where('id', '=', request()->get('id'))->first();
    $mail->status = 0;
    $mail->updated_by = auth()->user()->name;
    $mail->save();
    event(new MailDoneEvent($mail));
    if (request('inp') == 'custom') {
        $url = "https://wa.me/972" . request('tele') . "?text=" . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('txt')) . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('check'));
        return Redirect::away($url);

    } else {
        $url = "https://wa.me/972" . request('inp') . "?text=" . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('txt')) . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('check'));
            , 'success');
 return Redirect::away($url);
    }


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flash session like

```
public function whatsapp(Request $request)
{ 
    $whatsapp_log = new WhatsappLog();
    $whatsapp_log->telephone = request('tele') ?? request('inp');
    $whatsapp_log->calling_no = request('inp');
    $whatsapp_log->text = request('check') ? request('check') . '>' . request('txt') : request('txt');
    $whatsapp_log->log_by = auth()->user()->name;
    $whatsapp_log->save(); 
    $mail = mail::where('id', '=', request()->get('id'))->first();
    $mail->status = 0;
    $mail->updated_by = auth()->user()->name;
    $mail->save();
    event(new MailDoneEvent($mail));
    if (request('inp') == 'custom') {
        $url = "https://wa.me/972" . request('tele') . "?text=" . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('txt')) . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('check'));

    } else {
        $url = "https://wa.me/972" . request('inp') . "?text=" . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('txt')) . str_replace(' ', '%20', request('check'));
            , 'success');
    }

        session()->flash('url', $url);


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And in your view file

```
@if (session()->has('url'))
    <script>
        window.open('{{session()->get('url')}}', "_blank");
    </script>
@endif
```